# Using The CoinDesk API to Get Bitcoin Price Index Live Data

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

Does this hack of mine help retrieve Live Data from Coindesk's API? I wrote this with sheer passion but I hope there are PROs who can help with a much cleaner version of this code?

Take note of [www.cointelegraph.com](https://www.cointelegraph.com)

Does this execute the intended?

```
// Request Variable
var rqst = new XMLHttpRequest();

// GET request on the URL endpoint
rqst.open('GET', 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json', true);

rqst.onload = function () {

//store JSON in data variable
var data = JSON.parse(this.response);

//loop over data to retrieve specific thing
data.forEach(bpi => {

// do something with data like; append to header in HTML
});
}}
// Send request
rqst.send();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Unfortunately, questions like these are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because they address mostly the business logic instead of isolated programming issues. In case you have issues with the implementation of your system, try split your problem into [minimal, complete, and verifiable questions about programming issues](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: hello, how is off-topic please?

Comment: You want us to test your business logic. Stackoverflow is not a testing service nor a source code completion service. If there is an issue you must also clearly state the error message. Please read the links provided, this is just part of the review process, you always have the choice to edit and improve your own question. All comments can be later removed from here if you do so.